# Imgurl oauth2: 403 Unauthorized when allowing access

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, imgur

I have succesfully create an oauth connection with Imgur. It works find when logged in with one account, but now I doesn't anymore. I open my application, and Imgur asks if I want to allow the application ... security stuff. I allow. The result send back to my callback page:

```
{"data":{"error":"Unauthorized","request":"\/oauth2\/authorize","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":403}
```

It worked before, but it stopped working somehow.

I tried a different client Id and other accounts; nothing works

I call the page with this URL:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + environment.imgurClientId + "&response_type=token&state=APPLICATION_STATE
```

The client id is stored in the environment file.

In the end, I expect a access_token, not a 403 error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton No, I did not. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Comment: Yeah it seems like this is just Imgur's servers being overloaded